# Drupal integration for streaming video

Tags: panels

I am working with an STI product for wowza media server to allow streaming video on our website made in drupal 7. I am using panels for the profile pages which will have 8 guest camera docks which is simple enough. it will also have a text chat as well as a main video dock for the person who owns that profile. Anyone know how I might be able to set a flashvar to the userid of the profile by variable so i do not have to custom code each profile as people sign up? I want it so when a user signs up they have a profile with all the features and those features are specific to that user so that when one person goes to broadcast it doesnt broadcast to every profile.

Comment: What are you using to play the videos on the drupal site?

Comment: I am using a program called basic wowza chat that i bought from a guy. it is a web interface where a user can click to broadcast or use rtmp software like xsplit to do HD broadcasting. its all in flex and actionscript3 which i am still a newb at but figuring it out slowly just not sure how to grab the necessary information out of drupal to ensure the interface is unique to each profile page.

Comment: Is it a module for drupal?  To answer your question we need to know how the video player is being put on the site. Module, iframe, code pasted in a node, etc?

Comment: the players and chat are being added externally through custom panel content.

Comment: as of yet i have not even finished the code for the player and chat interface because i need to figure out how to pull info out of drupal to make it function correctly. but it will all go into a custom pane as php/html

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments and the fact you will be writing some custom code for the video player in your site. You can easily include the Drupal user id into flash variables.

In order to do this, you will load the Drupal [user object](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!globals.php/global/user/7) of the currently logged in user. This is quite easy to do.

```
<?php

$global $user;
$drupaluserid = $user->uid

?>
```

Comment: awesome that helps me a lot there now how would i use that in a flashvar i have not played with flashvars all that much. Right now the chat interface sits in a specific direction structure under the root of drupal. I was just using an iframe tag in panels to load it since there is a lot of required files in the chat folder i was not sure how to add the code direct to panels and have it work well. I do not need implicit details but the general gist of using a php variable as a flashvar.

Comment: i finished the code and the way it works is the flash app needs a unique identifier for each user that is broadcasting the "instance string" which should be the uid of the user with the chat on their profile not the user viewing the profile page. is that php you posted Brady for that?

Comment: OK the code is fully complete and I just need to understand how to add it all to drupal via a panel as custom content and to load all the files that go with the flash app?

Comment: Now you are getting to the complex part. You have to determine how you are going to create the video player. This is a very complicated question/answer that goes beyond the scope of your initial question which I answered. I would suggest creating a new discussion just for this.

Comment: I just need to know how to put the html into drupal properly since there are a lot of includes for the player html and the player html also has to be able to access the variables drupal creates.